# jquery tablesorter: Filtering by a column whose values are dynamically updated is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter, large-data

I have a `<table>`, with about 430 rows.  **No rows will be added or removed**, but they will *all* be updated with information gathered via AJAX (though not with the `pager` plugin; all data is on one page here).  I want to be able to sort and filter by these columns.  However, what I'm doing now is **very** slow:

```
$(function() {
    var table = $('table');
    var servers = $('.server');

    table.tablesorter({
        widgets: ['resizable', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                '.status-header': {
                    "In Progress" : function(e, n, f, i, $r, c, data) {
                        return e === "In Progress";
                    },
                    "OK" : function(e, n, f, i, $r, c, data) {
                        return e === "OK";
                    },
                    "Warning" : function(e, n, f, i, $r, c, data) {
                        return e === "Warning";
                    },
                    "Error" : function(e, n, f, i, $r, c, data) {
                        return e === "Error";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    table.on('filterStart', function(e) {
        table.trigger('updateAll');
    });

    servers.each(function(i, element) {
        var self = $(element);
        var version = self.find('.version');
        var status = self.find('.status');
        var link = self.find('.server-link').data('ask');

        var request = function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: link,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    version.text(data.version);
                }
            });
        };

        status.click(function(e) {
            version.text("Hold on");
            request();
        });

        request();
    });
});
```

That is, whenever I try to filter, the `<table>` is updated; but doing so takes a few seconds, which is unacceptable.  **How can I speed up the sorting and filtering of large tables whose values can change?**

Comment: Show more of your code

Comment: First off `table.trigger('updateAll');` shouldn't be used on filter start. An "upate" (not "updateAll") should be triggered *after* the ajax updates the table cells.

Comment: After each individual cell, or after *all* of them?  Because as it stands, from page load to the last AJAX call is about 40 seconds.  If there's a way I can get *that* down, I'd appreciate that too.

Comment: Where is the code that updates the table html?... after that is ALL done, trigger an "update". Or when the `status` is clicked, is it only updating one cell? It would help if I had **more information**. Is `servers` a bunch of cells in the table, is `status` a button for each server or a global button? If `servers` is a bunch of cells, wouldn't it be better to get all the server status in one ajax request?